# How can I compute $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{e^x-1}-e^x\sqrt{x}}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

How can I compute $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{e^x-1}-e^x\sqrt{x}}{x}?$$ I tried de L'Hospital, but it seems to make things worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Maclaurin expansions for $e^t$ and $\sqrt{1+t}$  as $t\to {0},$ we have
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{e^x-1}-e^x\sqrt{x}}{x}= \lim_{x \to 0+} \frac{\sqrt\frac{e^x-1}{x}-e^x}{\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt\frac{1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+o(x^2)-1}{x}-e^x}{\sqrt{x}} =\\
=\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{2!}+o(x)}-e^x}{\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1+ \frac{x}{4}+o(x)-1-x+o(x)}{\sqrt{x}}=\\=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{-\frac{3}{4}x+o(x)}{\sqrt{x}}=0.$$

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$\sqrt{e^x - 1} = \sqrt{x + O(x^2)} = \sqrt{x}\sqrt{1 + O(x)} = \sqrt{x}(1 + O(x)) = \sqrt{x} + o(x)$$
and
$$e^x\sqrt{x} = (1 + O(x))\sqrt{x} = \sqrt{x} + o(x).$$

So the limit is zero.

Comment: Did you forget dividing by $x$?

Comment: If I subtract and divide by $x$ I get $o(1)$.

Comment: Oh, I see. ${}$